# drupal_is_front div changer

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to find out how I can use drupal_is_front in order to remove the content_side DIV and rename the content_main DIV (for use with responsive design)

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is no function (built into core, at least) called `drupal_is_front()`. I believe what you're looking for is `drupal_is_front_page()` and in your case you could use it like this:

```
<div id="content_<?php if (drupal_is_front_page()): print 'main'; else: print 'something_else'; endif; ?>">
  ....
</div>
```

Or

```
<?php
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
  $divid = 'content_main';
}
else {
  $divid = 'content_something_else';
}
?>
  <div id="<?php print $divid; ?>">
    ....
  </div>
```

I think it's also worth mentioning that if you're applying the code to a template file, you should also be able to use the variable `$is_front` in place of the function `drupal_is_front_page()`. The difference might be minuscule, but using a variable rather than a function should save you a *little* bit of overhead on your server.